# Как с помощью QComboBox добавить данные в модель (базу данных)

Tags: pyqt5, qcombobox, qabstractlistmodel

В QComboBox данные поступают из модели (реализация QAbstractListModel).
QComboBox.setEditable(True)
Хочу, чтобы когда вводишь данные в Комбобокс по нажатию Enter новые данные добавлялись в модель. Сейчас у меня по сигналу returnPressed после ввода данных currentText() пустой. Соответственно и в модель добавляется пустая строка.
Другими словами, как мне сохранить текст перед нажатием Enter?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QComboBox,QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from myListModel import MyListModel,MyListListModel



mylist=[1,2,3,4]

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.cBox=QComboBox()
        model=MyListListModel(mylist)
        self.cBox.setModel(model)
        self.label=QLabel()
        self.cBox.setEditable(True)
        lineedit=self.cBox.lineEdit()
        lineedit.returnPressed.connect(self.addText)



        hbox=QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.cBox)
        hbox.addWidget(self.label)

        self.setLayout(hbox)

        self.setGeometry(300,300,300,150)
        self.show()
    
    def addText(self):
        if  self.cBox.currentIndex()<0:
            self.cBox.model().setData(self.cBox.currentText())
        
            



if __name__=='__main__':
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex=Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Пока реализовал такой костыль. Над QComboBox накладывается QLineEdit. Соответственно, по сигналу currentIndexChanged меняется текст в QLineEdit
Для QLineEdit устанавливается QСompleter от нашей же модели. Это нужно для того, что при вводе текста нам выдавался уже имеющийся в модели текст. Если текст новый, то при нажатии Enter, проверяется на то что текста нет в модели и вызывается setData модели. Еще надо реализовать, чтобы индекс QComboBox устанавливался в соответствии с введенным в QLineEdit текстом.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QComboBox,QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from myListModel import MyListListModel

mylist=[1,2,3,4]
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.cBox=QComboBox(self)
        self.cBox.setGeometry(200,80,300,20)
        model=MyListListModel(mylist)
        self.cBox.setModel(model)
        self.lineEdit=QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(200,80,280,20)
        self.lineEdit.setText(self.cBox.currentText())
        completer=QCompleter(model)
        self.lineEdit.setCompleter(completer)
        self.cBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.indexChanged)
        self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.addText)
        self.setGeometry(300,300,300,150)
        self.show()
    
    def indexChanged(self):
        self.lineEdit.setText(self.cBox.currentText())
 
    def addText(self):
        text=int(self.lineEdit.text())
        if  text not in self.cBox.model().results:
            self.cBox.model().setData(text)
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).